# Display text with <li> which contains <img>

Tags: css, html, image, html-lists

I have been trying to display text below or above the image like shown:

[image]

And currently, I am stuck with it only displaying images (example given):

[image]

I cannot use the exact code provided by W3schools as my thumbnails expand and switchs to responsive carousel when clicked. I only want name to appear with the thumbnails. I can't post my code so I have uploaded an image with my li> tags:

```
<div class="container">
    <ul id="myGallery">
        <li><img src="link.png" /></li>
        <li><img src="link.png" /></li>
        <li><img src="link.png" /></li>
        <li><img src="link.png" /></li>
        <li><img src="link.png" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: There is no text in the li in the image you've uploaded?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: When I added the code, it read that and only displayed the bulletpoints and not the actual code. Can we focus on the solution, please? Thanks.

Comment: @user: then follow the editing help in the editor more closely. You need to format your code as a codeblock (use the `{}` button).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `flex` to do that.

Something like below

```css
ul {
 list-style: none;
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
}

ul li {
  margin: 0 5px 5px 0;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul id="myGallery">
    <li>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/nature/1/" width="100px" height="100px" />
      <p>First image</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/nature/2/" width="100px" height="100px" />
      <p>Second image</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/nature/1/" width="100px" height="100px" />
      <p>Third image</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/nature/2/" width="100px" height="100px" />
      <p>Fourth image</p>
    </li>    
  </ul>
</div>
```

Second approach, use `figure`.

Something like below

```css
/*figure approach*/

.figures {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

figure {
  margin: 0;
  margin-right: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="figures">
  <figure>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/nature/1/" width="100px" height="100px" />
    <figcaption>First image</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/nature/2/" width="100px" height="100px" />
    <figcaption>Second image</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/nature/1/" width="100px" height="100px" />
    <figcaption>Third image</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/nature/2/" width="100px" height="100px" />
    <figcaption>Fourth image</figcaption>
  </figure>
</div>
```

#### Updates

Problem jsfiddle -  https://jsfiddle.net/raw9b1fj/2

Solution jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/raw9b1fj/4/

Comment: Hey, many thanks for the answers. I tried the first solution and although it works with what you showed, it doesn't work for me.  For the second method, I'd rather stick to li tags as it is linked to more of javascript and css files. I have already tried putting text between li tags, use other tags, etc. When I use your first method, it pushes down the other images and displays no text at all like shown - https://postimg.org/image/b30evte6x/

Comment: @user something is not right, please create a jsfiddle with sample content, it does have to actual content. - https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: I know something is messing it up. Here it is, hope it is enough. https://jsfiddle.net/raw9b1fj/2/

Comment: @user found problem in css `ul#myGallery` is having `font-size: 0` and `ul#myGallery li` is having `color: white`; just remove those and add image description then everything should be fine  - https://jsfiddle.net/raw9b1fj/4/ (updated fiddle)

Comment: Good news and a bad. In chrome, it would show the text area but not the text. I have tried applying styling to individual tags but no luck. (https://postimg.org/image/hzoqur435/) the same code seems to be working with Internet explorer but I am having trouble changing the width to full screen. - https://postimg.org/image/u51l9q3gf/

Comment: @user (for text issue): may be because `color` is `black` now, try to use some other color may be blue, red and see if that works then you can adjust color accordingly. new updated link - https://jsfiddle.net/raw9b1fj/5/. Seems issue is related to `color: white` so dont remove that and see.

Comment: Okay, nevermind, it is working now. Just had to clear the cached data from the browser. Thanks a ton! now I have to figure out why it displays only two images per row. Thanks again!